# Youtube-dl error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7766645.83333'

Tags: youtube-dl, mpd

I am trying to download a video from an .mpd file and I'm getting the following error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7766645.83333'`

When I look in the .mpd file, it has these `<S>` elements, some of them containing the float.

```
<S t="636000000" d="6000000"/>
<S t="642000000" d="6000000"/>
<S t="648000000" d="7766645.83333"/>
```

The program seems to have a problem with `d` being a float. However if the segments are displayed like so:

```
<SegmentURL media="segment-1.m4s"/>
<SegmentURL media="segment-2.m4s"/>
<SegmentURL media="segment-3.m4s"/>
```

Then there is no issue. Is there a workaround for this? Is there a way I can convert this .mpd file to a format that youtube-dl can handle. I am currently using the **2018.06.25** version of youtube-dl.

Comment: Which URL are you downloading? This should just be fixed in youtube-dl, but neither I nor anybody else can realistically do so without being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same issue have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Read the backtrace when the error happens. You'll notice it points you to source code `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py`, or something similar. When you open that file:line, you'll see something like

```
't': int(s.get('t', 0)),
 # @d is mandatory (see [1, 5.3.9.6.2, Table 17, page 60])
'd': int(s.attrib['d']),
'r': r,
```

Change the 2 `int` to `float` seems to solve the problem temporarily.